# How to hide API key when developing pure html/ js website

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-development-server, api-key

I'm new to web development and I'm creating a pure html/ css/ and js website and host it on  a server. I have to use an API key in my js file and of course I don't want it to be exposed to public. in my research I've learned that there is no easy way to actually mask my key and it can only be done with a proper backend.

Now my question is that is there a way to only have the api key on the backend and get it to the js file on front end to do the rest of the functions? if yes how?

Sorry if this question is repetitive but I couldn't find an answer when I searched the forums.

```
myhtml.html


a regular html with <script></script> tag to myjs.js
```

```
myjs.js


API="something"


initilize-library (API); 

// use the library
```

I haven't try anything specific since most of the solutions I found were for frameworks such as react and not specific enough (They say you need a backend but not much on how to implement it and how to connect to what I already have which is an html, css , and js files)

I know we can have secret files and folders on hosting servers and I was thinking of storing my JS there but it didnt work

Comment: Store API keys in localstorage or cookies

Comment: The localStorage object allows you to save key/value pairs in the browser.

Comment: `of course I don't want it to be exposed to public`... if it gets into the browser **in any way whatsoever** then it's public.

Comment: `get it to the js file on front end to do the rest of the functions`...you could do that, but then the key will still be in the JS code, and will therefore be discoverable (fairly trivially, just by using the browser's Developer Tools - either via the JS debugger, or it'll likely then be visible in the Network tool inside any requests sent to the API). See my first comment.

Comment: `I was thinking of storing my JS there but it didnt work`...no of course it wouldn't because, in order for that JS to be executed, it has to be sent to the user's browser.

Comment: If the key is really secret and you can't risk it leaking, and isn't specific to the user who is using the site at that time, then you simply have to use server-side code as a proxy to speak to the API.

Comment: Thank you ADyson, it seems my only option is using something like php for server side ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can say is the Server-Side option, I already read all that the guys said, and I found that using `localStorage` is not safe, however, server-side may be a better option, you can call the script API (I mean except calling it like `<script data-secret="123123"></script>` you directly Build it and Inisialise it) directly.

Another Option would be using Server-Side API, If the library you wish Inisialise has API, you can use the API to fetch the data and do your process on that, then, publish it into the Client-Side

```php
// in this example we want to get the Clients' IP Details from an API and show to them

// code written in PHP

$secret="123123";
$data = file_get_contents("https://api.myip.example/v1/getIPdetails?secret=$secret&ip=1.1.1.1");

echo $data;
```

The only thing that users/clients can see on their screens is something like this.

```html
<!-- pre is like a tag for PHP, ignore it -->
<pre>
DATA WE GOT FROM THE API
</pre>
```

See!, No API key was exposed, also, clients don't know where we got those details.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I appericiate the details and will give it a try :)

Comment: @Artemis, No problem, If you had time, go and read about `.env` as well, it would be helpful when you have too many secrets.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach than sticking your API directly into the code is to have the server side script call for the api from a separate file. (Php likely since you're doing web dev).